# MWAA (aws managed airflow) failed to pause DAG when using CLI

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am trying to pause a DAG as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-airflow-ui.html) but getting 'Dag id testDag not found' even though the DAG exists.

The error message says that my 3rd party module 'not found' even though it works when I trigger the DAG.

I saw this on the doc :

> Note
> Any command that parses a DAG (such as list_dags, backfill) will fail if the DAG uses plugins that depend on packages that are installed through requirements.txt.

Dag code (testDag):

```
from datetime import timedelta
# my_client is the 3rd party library
from client import my_client
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}
dag = DAG(
    'testDag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False
)

def print_me_func(**context):
    print("hiiiii")

printMe = PythonOperator(
    task_id='printMe',
    dag = dag,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_me_func,
)
```

Airflow API :

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
import base64

mwaa_env_name = 'YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME'
dag_name = 'testDag'

client = boto3.client('mwaa')

mwaa_cli_token = client.create_cli_token(
    Name=mwaa_env_name
)

mwaa_auth_token = 'Bearer ' + mwaa_cli_token['CliToken']
mwaa_webserver_hostname = 'https://{0}/aws_mwaa/cli'.format(mwaa_cli_token['WebServerHostname'])
raw_data = "pause {0}".format(dag_name)

mwaa_response = requests.post(
    mwaa_webserver_hostname,
    headers={
        'Authorization': mwaa_auth_token,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    data=raw_data
)

mwaa_std_err_message = base64.b64decode(mwaa_response.json()['stderr']).decode('utf8')
mwaa_std_out_message = base64.b64decode(mwaa_response.json()['stdout']).decode('utf8')

print(mwaa_response.status_code)
print(mwaa_std_err_message)
print(mwaa_std_out_message)
```

```
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 421, in pause
    set_is_paused(True, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 431, in set_is_paused
    is_paused=is_paused,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1887, in set_is_paused
    raise DagNotFound("Dag id {} not found".format(self.dag_id))
airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id testDag not found

[2021-03-23 20:37:45,790] {{dagbag.py:259}} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/testDag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/testDag.py", line 2, in <module>
    from client import my_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'
[2021-03-23 20:37:45,802] {{dagbag.py:259}} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/testDag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/testDag.py", line 2, in <module>
    from client import my_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'
```

Any workarounds that I can use ?
Thanks

Comment: Add your DAG code and the specific error traceback

Answer (score 0):

Seems like MWAA 1.10.12 has a serialization issue, the same code works when migrating from MWAA 1.10.12 to MWAA 2.0.2.

Answer (score -1):

I am using 2.2.2 and still have the same issue, looks like the plugins are not  getting installed to web server where the MWAA cli cmds are getting executed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33029605)